# Decoding a JSON object and echo a specific value?

Tags: php, json, decode

I have a PHP page where I reference a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
  "body": {
    "zip": "02110",
    "stores": [
      {
        "storeEmail": "email@email.com",
        "storeName": "Name",
        "city": "City",
        "Availability": {
          "123": {
            "Quote": "daily",
            "Display": "available",
          }
        },
      },
```

Each JSON object contains multiple "stores", above is one example.

I can currently echo the store name by using this:

```
echo "<br>".$phpArray->body->stores{0}->storeName;
```

How do I echo the value "123" from the sample JSON? I would also like to echo the quote as a separate variable. The value "123" will change for different searches. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$phpArray = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($phpArray['body']['stores'] as $store) {
    echo $store['storeName'];
    foreach{$store['Availabilty'] as $avail => $info) { 
        echo $avail; // 123
        echo $info['Quote'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I am getting the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) pointing to the line: echo $store['storeName'];

Comment: Whoops, missed a parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

```
$b = json_decode($a); 
var_dump(key($b->body->stores{0}->Availability)); 
var_dump(reset($b->body->stores{0}->Availability)->Quote);
```

or a loop for stores

```
foreach($b->body->stores as $store) {
    var_dump(key($store->Availability)); 
    var_dump(reset($store->Availability)->Quote);
}
```

Comment: Using the first approach, I get an error: Warning: key() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given  pointing to the first var_dump line

Comment: I use `'{"body":{"zip":"02110","stores":[{"storeEmail":"email@email.com","storeName":"Name","city":"City","Availability":{"123":{"Quote":"daily","Display":"available"}}}]}}'` for $a